# Creating a graphic from the data of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe

I have this list:

```
[(200, array([1.81101387])), (300, array([2.73324657])), (400, array([3.66660659])), (500, array([4.61826639])), (600, array([5.57527109])), (700, array([6.54331291])), (800, array([7.5340437])), (900, array([8.53877086])), (1000, array([9.54263164])), (1100, array([10.57365805])), (1200, array([11.61853761])), (1300, array([12.67720361])), (1400, array([13.74957748])), (1500, array([14.83556906])), (1600, array([15.93507691])), (1700, array([17.07408599])), (1800, array([18.20190138])), (1900, array([19.37230333])), (2000, array([20.52788386])), (2100, array([21.72908566])), (2200, array([22.94628865])), (2300, array([24.14308228])), (2400, array([25.38997665])), (2500, array([26.65224533])), (2600, array([27.9296472])), (2700, array([29.26490691])), (2800, array([30.57345122])), (2900, array([31.89630179])), (3000, array([33.2811809])), (3100, array([34.63333589])), (3200, array([36.05016039])), (3300, array([37.43023372])), (3400, array([38.87746378])), (3500, array([40.34008923])), (3600, array([41.81764985])), (3700, array([43.30966982])), (3800, array([44.81565878])), (3900, array([46.33511277]))]
```

It's elements are (height, time) and I would like to know how to create a graphic of this (erasing what says array()).

An idea I have is to create a dataframe with pandas and then represent the columns. The problem is that I don't know how to separate the elements in order to introduce them into a dataframe.

Thanks.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`  is your friend ...  then `plt.plot(var1, var2)`

Comment: array([2.73324657]) looks like a function call. can you provide the code ? but yes maltplotlib is the solution

Comment: array([...]) is most likely a numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work (assuming x is time and y is height)

```
import pandas as pd

# add the following lines if you have to copy and paste your data
from numpy import array
data = [(200, array([1.81101387])), (300, array([2.73324657])), (400, array([3.66660659])), (500, array([4.61826639])), (600, array([5.57527109])), (700, array([6.54331291])), (800, array([7.5340437])), (900, array([8.53877086])), (1000, array([9.54263164])), (1100, array([10.57365805])), (1200, array([11.61853761])), (1300, array([12.67720361])), (1400, array([13.74957748])), (1500, array([14.83556906])), (1600, array([15.93507691])), (1700, array([17.07408599])), (1800, array([18.20190138])), (1900, array([19.37230333])), (2000, array([20.52788386])), (2100, array([21.72908566])), (2200, array([22.94628865])), (2300, array([24.14308228])), (2400, array([25.38997665])), (2500, array([26.65224533])), (2600, array([27.9296472])), (2700, array([29.26490691])), (2800, array([30.57345122])), (2900, array([31.89630179])), (3000, array([33.2811809])), (3100, array([34.63333589])), (3200, array([36.05016039])), (3300, array([37.43023372])), (3400, array([38.87746378])), (3500, array([40.34008923])), (3600, array([41.81764985])), (3700, array([43.30966982])), (3800, array([44.81565878])), (3900, array([46.33511277]))]
##

x, y = [item[1][0] for item in data], [item[0] for item in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'time': x, 'height': y})
```

You can also check that your data is sorted by time by adding this line:

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. Why are you saying item [1] [0] and then item [0]? Just to know, it works perfectly.

Comment: each item in the array looks like this: (y, array([x]), which is essentially (y, [x]) since you can access numpy arrays in the same way as python ones. Therefore, y = item[0] and x is item[1][0] since we have to access the array within the array

Answer (score 0):

You could unzip your data structure to `x` and `y` and then plot them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from numpy import array 

a = [(200, array([1.81101387])), (300, array([2.73324657])), (400, array([3.66660659])), (500, array([4.61826639])), (600, array([5.57527109])), (700, array([6.54331291])), (800, array([7.5340437])), (900, array([8.53877086])), (1000, array([9.54263164])), (1100, array([10.57365805])), (1200, array([11.61853761])), (1300, array([12.67720361])), (1400, array([13.74957748])), (1500, array([14.83556906])), (1600, array([15.93507691])), (1700, array([17.07408599])), (1800, array([18.20190138])), (1900, array([19.37230333])), (2000, array([20.52788386])), (2100, array([21.72908566])), (2200, array([22.94628865])), (2300, array([24.14308228])), (2400, array([25.38997665])), (2500, array([26.65224533])), (2600, array([27.9296472])), (2700, array([29.26490691])), (2800, array([30.57345122])), (2900, array([31.89630179])), (3000, array([33.2811809])), (3100, array([34.63333589])), (3200, array([36.05016039])), (3300, array([37.43023372])), (3400, array([38.87746378])), (3500, array([40.34008923])), (3600, array([41.81764985])), (3700, array([43.30966982])), (3800, array([44.81565878])), (3900, array([46.33511277]))]

x = [_[0] for _ in a]
y = [_[1][0] for _ in a]
# Here it could be also y = [_[1] for _ in a], but we are dealing here with the fact that you have plenty of one-element arrays

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```